# Failure to connect to a relational database

Tags: databases

I'm trying to use the V12 functionality to connect to a PostgreSQL database on my local machine.  I start with

```
dbref1 = DatabaseReference[{"Backend" -> "postgres", "Port" -> 5432, 
   "Host" -> "localhost", "Username" -> "mark", 
   "Password" -> "redacted", "Name" -> "cwd"}]
```

and a `DatabaseReference` is returned.  The details all look correct. I then try

```
rdb = DatabaseConnect[dbref1]
```

and evaluation never completes.  However, pretty quickly *Mathematica* reports an error, for which the stack trace shows.

```
Message[ByteArray::batd, {EndOfFile}, "Byte"]

ByteArray[{EndOfFile}]
```

I get the same error message, and the same eternal evaluation, if I try

```
rdb = RelationalDatabase[dbref1]
```

I'm confident that I have the database (etc) identified and specified correctly since I can continue to use the pre-V12 approach using `OpenSQLConnection`.

I'm running Mathematica 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019) on OS X 10.11.6.  I'm running PostgreSQL 10.7.

Can anyone see anything I'm doing that I shouldn't be, or *vice-versa* ?

Resolution: I never did solve the problem but it went away when I upgraded to v12.1.

Comment: This looks like a bug. It would be really great if you could create some minimal example `.sql` dump that would reproduce this behavior. PostgresSQL has definitely been tested, but there always is a chance that our tests didn't cover some types of db structure. It is perfectly understandable if creating some minimal example is not an option for you, it is just that it would be harder to reproduce this then. You could use the tech. support channel if you don't want to make this public.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: thanks for your swift response.  I'll ask this again on Tech Support since it looks like it might entail sending some of the database over; it's not secret or even sensitive, but would probably just clutter the site unnecessarily.  I won't delete this version, the eventual answer might be of interest to this site too.

Comment: There is a planned bugfix update for relational db functionality that is coming out very soon (mostly Oracle support, but also some bugs fixed). If you write to the tech support soon (over the weekend or Monday), we will look at it right away and if there is a bug, make an effort to push the fix into this update.  I will post some answer here once it becomes clear what the problem is.

Comment: I already copied the question to Tech Support.  I'll await developments, but don't feel you need to interrupt your weekend on this, this question arises from some of my more recreational use of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have direct access to what tech. support gets, so it will have to wait until Monday anyway :)

Comment: One quick question: do you happen to have installed / used a version of [Wolfram client for Python](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython) from github (different from the default one that comes in the layout)?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I mean, I haven't deliberately sought it out and installed it.  Python is a language I happily pay Mathematica's licence fees to avoid :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks. That was just to make sure, since there could be versions mismatch (we use Python internally).

Comment: Hey Mark, the folks from tech. support tell me that they emailed you some time ago asking for some more details, but didn't get the reply from you yet. Is this still relevant for you? We can now reproduce this bug on a certain Oracle db (and also not in all cases / on all machines), and in general it seems to be quite elusive. Would help  to have more reproducible cases. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't see anything from them, but will check.  Yes, it's still relevant but I'm in a low-connectivity zone so tell your colleagues not to expect instant feedback.  Thanks for contacting me through this 'back-channel'.

Comment: Sure, thanks for getting back. The end address of all this communication is anyway our team (most likely me),  so no worries. Just let me know if you don't find that email in your inbox, I will ask them to re-send it.

Comment: FWIW: v12.1 has fixed this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info, good to know. We weren't able to reproduce this exact problem locally, but we've seen somewhat similar ones. We have moved from the direct communication with the part of the system that executes the queries (and lives in another process) to zeromq socket - based communication, which is the likely reason this problem went away.